# Would it be better for me to use 2 applet classes or have 1 applet class and a normal class

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

My problem is this so right now i have 2 different applet classes one for the title screen of applet and then another for my actual menu. They each do something differently in the paint method, so i wanna know if i can run my main class and then launch my second class from my main class

or if it would be better just call my second class from the main class for drawing things and other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my limited experience with applets, usually you have one class that extends Applet -- or better JApplet since Swing is much more robust and flexible. If you need to do painting, do so in a class that extends JPanel or JComponent and draw in its paintComponent method override. You can then display the JPanel in the applet when necessary.

For more specific help, please give us more information on the specifics of your code and your problem.